# Can't figure out how to print horizontally in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to print this code:

```
for x in range (1, 21):  

    if x%15==0:
        print("fizzbuzz")

    elif x%5==0:
        print("buzz") 
    elif x%3==0:
        print("fizz")

    else:
        print (x)
```

Horizontally instead of it printing vertically, like this:

```
1

2

3
```

to

```
1 2 3
```

I am not sure how to, some help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Two options:

Accumulate a result string and `print` that at the end:

```
result = ""  
for x in range (1, 21):  

    if x%15==0:
        result = result + "fizzbuzz "

    etc...
print result
```

Or tell Python not to end the printed string with a newline character. In Python 3, which you seem to be using, you do this by setting the `end` argument of the `print` function, which is `"\n"` (a newline) by default:

```
for x in range (1, 21):  

    if x%15==0:
        print("fizzbuzz",end=" ")

    etc...
```

Historical note: In Python 2, this could be achieved by adding a comma at the end of the `print` statement; `print "fizzbuzz",`

Comment: I'm not the downvoter; in fact I just upvoted, because I believe the OP is using Python 3, not 2 (given the way he wrote his print functions/statements). And if he's using Python 3, then this answer is the best one.

Comment: I modified it and it works great with the end=" " thanks very much for that!

Answer (score 4):

do this and it will print all on one line:

```
for x in range (1, 21):  

    if x%15==0:
        print ("fizzbuzz"),

    elif x%5==0:
        print ("buzz"), 
    elif x%3==0:
        print ("fizz"),

    else:
        print (x),
```

it will print like this:

`1 2 fizz 4 buzz fizz 7 8 fizz buzz 11 fizz 13 14 fizzbuzz 16 17 fizz 19 buzz`

Comment: I believe the OP is using Python 3, not 2, from looking at his use of print functions rather than print statements -- in which case this answer will be incorrect. If he is using Python 3, the `end=" "` approach in the other answer is better.

Comment: I am using 3 yes, the result of what Christian has said still prints vertically.

Comment: Ohhhh very sorry im not using 3 but i will keep my asnwer incase someone stumbles upon this question and is using 2 sorry about that :)

Comment: No worries, I got the code to work with the end=" " thanks for the tutorial for 2 though =)

Answer (score 2):

A '\n' character is written at the end, unless the print statement ends with a comma.

http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html

Comment: This is for Python2, the original question targets Python 3 where you get that effect with using `print( ... , end='')`, effectively redefining the "end of string" to be empty instead of the default `\n`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it tells each line what to end with and separates it with a coma for easier reading:

```
for x in range (1, 21):
    if x%15==0:
        print("fizzbuzz", end = ", ") 
    elif x%5==0:
        print("buzz", end = ", ")

    elif x%3==0:
        print("fizz", end = ", ")
    
    else: 
        print (x,  end = ", ")
```