# Printing on the same line

Tags: python-3.x

I need for this code to print horizontally and I've looked around but none of the answers seem to work for me.

```
for x in range (1,20): 
    if x % 5 == 0 and x % 3 == 0:
            print ('FizzBuzz')            
    elif x % 3 == 0: 
        print ('Fizz')

    elif x % 5 == 0: 
        print ('Buzz')        
    else: 
        print (x)    .
```

Comment: Show us what you've looked at, and in what way they didn't "seem to work". Because there are lots of perfectly good answers out there that work perfectly well, and we have no idea which ones you looked at and what was wrong with them, so we can't help you.

Comment: Meanwhile, the most obvious problem in your code is `print (x)    .`, That stray `.` will raise a `SyntaxError` before anything runs. Also, the haphazard mix of indentation implies that you might be mixing spaces and tabs, which could easily lead to either an `IndentationError`, or the code running but not doing what you expect it to.

Comment: Oh my god, here it is, an example of someone who can't solve FizzBuzz. And I thought it was a joke!

Comment: @sberry: Not if he's using Python 3. (And if he's using Python 2, the parentheses around the `print` arguments are unnecessary and misleading.)

Comment: Guys - relax, he **can** and did solve fizzbuzz - his question was how to print it horizontally - the problem is that every `print` also prints a newline!

Comment: Meanwhile, when I try each of these `print` calls, they all print horizontally. Perhaps you've got a 1-character-wide terminal, or you've set your monitor on its side?

Comment: I have looked at the comments in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458024/cant-figure-out-how-to-print-horizontally-in-python and my end result was still print vertically

Comment: OK, so you copied the code out of Jessica Smith's question, which has a problem, instead of copying the code out of any of the answers there, which do not, and now you want to know why you have the same problem as Jessica?

Comment: @abamet: being stuck on Python2, I often wonder about those types of differences.  I am never sure whether someone is on one or the other unless they tag it as such.  As far as parens being misleading, I agree mostly, but I am seeing it more and more these days.

Comment: @sberry: I'm mostly seeing it on code from people who copy someone else's Python 3 code and try to use it in Python 2, or who refuse to say after being asked 3 times whether they're on 2 or 3, get an answer for 3, and then use it in 2…

Comment: Why would anyone upvote a question which is just "I copied this code (incorrectly) from another question and now have the same problem as that copied code"?

Comment: @abarnert: lolz, and come to think of it, you are probably right.

Comment: What's the correct reason to vote to close here? I want "lacks minimal effort"...

Comment: @abarnert oh come on - they've changed the `range` and introduced a superfluous `.` :p

Comment: I wrote this code out by myself and it works properly and I only searched the web after I couldn't figure out how to print horizontally

Comment: @PatrickCollins: I think at this point it's a dup, since he has literally copied and pasted the code from the other question he linked to (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458024/cant-figure-out-how-to-print-horizontally-in-python), except for introducing some new typos, and has exactly the same problem as that code. How much more dup can you get?

Comment: @abarnert I tend to agree... I'm not quite sure what more can be done here...

Comment: I really, really hope that he hasn't successfully talked his way through a job interview because of this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Change print statements to

print ('FizzBuzz', end=' ') or print ('FizzBuzz'), ==> python 3 syntax

print 'FizzBuzz', ==> python 2.* syntax

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sys` module:

```
import sys 
for x in range (1,20): 
    if x % 5 == 0 and x % 3 == 0:
        sys.stdout.write('FizzBuzz ')            
    elif x % 3 == 0: 
        sys.stdout.write('Fizz ')

    elif x % 5 == 0: 
        sys.stdout.write('Buzz ')        
    else: 
        sys.stdout.write(str(x)+' ')
```

Comment: Downvoting without a comment is lame...

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly (which is hard) I guess you meant that you want to print without newline:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('.')
```

or (in case you are using python 2)

```
print('Buzz'),
```

and in case you are using python 3 (https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html):

```
print('Buzz', end="")
```

Here is an answer: [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space)

Comment: If he's using Python 3, the comma outside the parens will not work. If he's using Python 2, it will work, but it's very misleading.

Comment: @abarnert - 10x. I've changed it

Answer (score -1):

Well I think this is what your looking for:

```
print('hello world', end='')
print('. And some more on the same line', end='')
```

Doc: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print

Comment: Is the `git` at the end a Freudian slip, your brain inserting a comment on the questioner?

Comment: @abarnert Thats my os not alt-tabbing properly :D