# Python: print repeat error, repeats inputs

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I made a program that would some up a grade average. Everything seems fine, the only problem, when I run the program at the end it prints out like this:

```
Jack
5
10
6
7.0
Stacy
10
8
9
9.0
Jack
5
10
6
7.0
Stacy
10
8
9
9.0
Jack
5
10
6
7.0
Stacy
10
8
9
9.0
```

How can I make the program print out, for example:

```
Name Grade1 Grade2 Grade3 (etc) Average
Name2 Grade1 Grade2 Grade3 (etc) Average2

etc
```

separately for every student's name used?

```
grades = []       
names = []         
ch = 1               
while (ch!=0):                         
    name = input('Enter a name: ')         
    if (name.isalpha()):           
        grade = int(input('Enter a grade: '))
        if(grade <= 10 and grade > 0):     
            names.append(name)         
            grades.append(grade)       
        else:
            while (grade <= 0) or (grade > 10):
                print ('The grade you entered is not correct, try again!')
                grade = int (input('Enter a grade: '))
            names.append(name)
            grades.append(grade)
    elif(name == '0'):
        print ('A zero was entered, end of program.')
        ch = 0   
    else:
        print ('The name was entered wrong, try again!')
#problem probably starts from here
howmuch = len(grades)                   
result = []                               
for k in range(0, howmuch):
    nreal = names[k]                             
    for i in range(0, howmuch):           
        if (nreal == names[i]):         
            result.append(grades[i])
    greal = len(result)
    sumup = 0
    print (nreal)
    howmuch = len(names)
    for z in range(0,greal):
        a = result[z]
        b= int(a)
        print (b)
        sumup = sumup + b
    avg = sumup /(z+1)
    print (avg)
    result = []
```

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: So that it would be like:
Name Grade Average/
Name2 Grade2 Average2

So it would be in one line for each student.

Comment: Use print(variable, end = " ") (Notice the comma after the variable) Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18908897/whats-ending-comma-in-print-function-for) link

Answer (score 0):

Add a comma at the end of the print statements where you do not want a new line.

```
print nreal,
...
    print b,
    ...
print avg
```

Comment: right ... i was confused by the space between print and the parentheses ... which would be correct in python 2 but i see there is also an `input`

Answer (score 0):

by default python adds a \n to the end of every print call. To fix that add a second parameter to print. `print(string, end="")`

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, which is what you seem to be using, you can print "[horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458024/cant-figure-out-how-to-print-horizontally-in-python)" by setting the end argument of the print function, which is "\n" (a newline) by default, like this:

```
...
print (nreal, end = " ")
...
   print (b, end = " ")
```

Leave your last print statement as is: `print (avg)` since you want it to print a newline for printing the next student's information.